# Make the page wait for the submit to finish before redirecting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, form-submit

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC3 webapplication

I am using Jquery to submit multiple forms

```
for (var i = 0; i < AllForms.length; i++) {
            $(AllForms[i]).trigger('submit');
        }
```

and after that I am redirecting to the Home page

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
```

My question is this, The forms submit is being done asynchronously, and sometimes the page is redirecting before all the submits are over.

How can I make the page wait for the submit to finish and then redirect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var formCount = $('form').length;
$('form').each(function() {
    jQuery.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function() {
        formCount--;
        if(formCount === 0) {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
        }
    });
});
```

Give this a try.  This is a simplified version, but perhaps you'd want an additional check if it the ajax request was sent successfully.